# Angular HPM error while trying to proxy request /oauth/token

Tags: angular, oauth, proxy

I tried to run my Angular and it is compiled successfully. I can open the UI at the browser that displays the login page.

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
```

But then I got this error and cannot proceed to access my application.

```
[HPM] POST /oauth/token -> http://localhost:8090
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /oauth/token from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:8090 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/erro
rs.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Here's my `proxy.conf.json` file:

```
{
  "/api/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8090",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
  "/oauth/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8090",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

The login credentials I used works just fine in staging though. Anyone had the same issues? I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Is your API server running at port 8090 on your machine?

Comment: Have you checked if `http://localhost:8090/oauth/token` works? It seems to be unavailable

Comment: I tried `netstat -an` and can't see port 8090 running. The link `http://localhost:8090/oauth/token` also doesn't work. How do I fix that?